# is there an algorithm for this array problem?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I'm struggling to find an algorithm for this problem that runs in **O(n) worst case time**.

Let's say you have an array, of n elements, with the value of the elements being either 1 or 0. I need to calculate the number of sub-arrays where there exists more 1's inside the sub-array than there are 0's outside the sub-array.

what i tried to do:

i tried to first make a prefix-sum array of the input array, this is so that when given a sub-array, we grab the start and end indexes of the sub array, look at the corresponding values in the prefix array -> we can find out the number of 1s in the sub-array in O(n) time.

for example:

`input array =         [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]`

`prefix sum array = [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7]`

`example sub array = [1,0,0,1]`

`start index = 0, end index = 3`

`prefix[3+1] - prefix[0] = 2 - 0 = 2` (two 1s inside the sub

array)

I am not sure where to go from here. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: first try to solve *without* an upper bound

Comment: Make a prefix sum array but for the zeroes? Effectively a prefix sum array of the complement of the input array. You can then count the number of zeroes inside (and outside) of any subarray, just like you do with the ones.

Comment: @Nelfeal but. that wouldnt be O(nlogn) time? wouldnt that be O(n)?

Comment: @ferocioussprouts O(n) is also O(n log n) (but not the other way around). Why would you want a O(n log n) when you can have a O(n)?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny, apologies it should be O(n), will edit my post

Comment: @ferocioussprouts _than there are 0's outside the sub-array_ Did you mean inside and not _outside_ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of sub-arrays with more ones inside than zeroes outside is the i-th triangular number, where i is the number of ones in the entire input array. Here is a proof.

Let `n` be the number of elements in the input array, and `i` the number of ones in the input array.

For any sub-array `A`, let `s(A)` be its size (number of elements inside), and let `v(A)` be its value, that is the number of ones inside minus the number of zeroes outside. The sub-array counts if `v(A) > 0`.

The only sub-array of size `n` has value `i` (if `s(A) = n`, then `v(A) = i`), so if `i > 0`, that sub-array counts.

For any sub-array `A` and two constants `t` and `w`,
if `s(A) = t => v(A) = w` then `s(A) = t-1 => v(B) = w-1`.
In other words, if all sub-arrays of size `t` have value `w`, then all sub-arrays of size `t-1` have value `w-1`. This is because any sub-array of size `t-1` can be obtained by excluding an element from a sub-array of size `t`, and whatever that element is, its exclusion decreases the value of the sub-array by exactly 1: it's either 1 more zero outside, or 1 less one inside.

By induction, for any sub-array `A`, if `s(A) = n-t` then `v(A) = i-t`. Additionally, the converse is true: if `v(A) = i-t` then `s(A) = n-t`, because if `s(A) != s(B)` then `v(A) != v(B)`.

For any sub-array `A`, `A` counts only if `v(A) = i-t` where `t < i`, so only if `s(A) = n-t` where `t < i`. There are `n-(t-1)` sub-arrays of size `t` (1 of size n, 2 of size n-1, ..., n of size 1), so there are `n-(n-t-1) = t+1` sub-arrays of size `n-t`. And the sum of `t+1` from `t = 0` to `t = i-1` equals `i*(i+1)/2`, also known as the i-th triangular number.

In conclusion, count the number of ones in the input array and compute the corresponding triangular number. In pseudo-code:

```
input_array = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
ones_count = 0

for i in input_array
    if i == 1 then ones_count++

answer = ones_count * (ones_count+1) / 2
```

Comment: would you be able to provide an example in your answer?

Comment: @ferocioussprouts there you go, I also fixed a few inaccuracies and reformatted it.

Comment: how does this work for the input array [1,0,0,1]? the only subarray that satisifies the condtion is [1,0,0,1], so the number of subarrays is 1, but your algorithm returns 3?

Comment: `[1,0,0]` and `[0,0,1]` also satisfy the condition: there is 1 one inside and 0 zero outside, and 1 > 0.

Answer (score 2):

It is a very strange constraint, but after making the following observation it becomes easy:

Enlarging the sub-array always improves its value. We define the value `v = i - o`, whith `i` being the ones inside the sub-array and `o` the number of zeros outside the sub-array. Now another way to formulate the problem is: count all sub-arrays with a value greater than zero. Here is why the value always improves when enlarging the array:

- adding a 0 to the sub-array: `v = i - (o - 1) = i - o + 1` this is one greater compared to `i - o`.
- adding a 1 to the sub-array: `v = (i + 1) - o = i - o + 1` this is one greater compared to `i - o`.

So we can see that enlarging the sub-array not only increases its value, **enlarging the sub-array by n elements increases the score exactly by n**. Also decreasing the size of the sub-array by n decreases its value by n. This leads to the conclusion that **we can calculate a minimum size for the sub-array and then use that number and the array size to get the number of sub-arrays fullfilling the condition**.

So here is an O(n) algorithm:

1. Count the number of 0s in the array => `z`
2. if `z = n` return 0
3. The size making the value 0 is: `m = z` (by counting the zeros we look at it like having a sub-array of size 0, so the number of ones inside is 0 and the number of zeros outside is `z`, this gives a value `v = 0 - z = -z`, so if we increase the size by `z` we get a value of 0)
4. So finally we can start at index 0 with a sub-array, here we can count all sub-arrays of sizes `m < size < n`, so the number of sub-arrays for index 0 is `n - m`, at index 1 it is `n - m - 1` and at index `i` it is `n - m - i` (as long as the therm is > 0). Because we know the term will reach zero because the minimum size for the sub-array is 1 we can get the following formula: **count = (n - m) * (n - m + 1) / 2**

**And condensed: count the number of 0s `z` and return `(n - z) * (n - z + 1) / 2`**

**Which is the same as counting the number of 1s `i` and return `i * (i + 1) / 2`** (because n - z = i)

Comment: I'd rather count the number of ones `i` and return `i*(i+1)/2`, aka the i-th triangular number.

Comment: @maraca, would be able to provide an example in your answer? im getting quite lost in your step 4 of the algorithm

Comment: @ferocioussprouts in step 4 we ask ourselves how many sub-arrays starting at index 0 fullfill the condition, the answer is n - z (those with sizes z + 1, z + 2, ..., n). Then we look at the next index and we can see it is the same except that we don't have the largest size any more. So going through all the indexes we get: (n - z) + (n - z - 1) + (n - z - 2) + ... + 2 + 1. So we just need to sum the numbers from 1 to n - z, for this we can use the formula. And because n - z = i we can write it even nicer. If we would have focussed on ones right away we might have gotten it directly.